# ArcMap field calculator VBScript

Tags: arcgis-10.0, vbscript

I want to do some advanced level scripting with VBA in the field calculator. I have done a simple coding in the code block. Here is the codes.

```
dim X
  if [Name]="University" then
    X=101101
  elseif [Name]= "College" then
    X=101102
  elseif [Name]= "Medical College" then
    X=101103
  elseif [Name]= "School" then
    X=101104
  else
    X=""
  end if
```

This is working correctly. But I want to do something more. Those are-

1. If the Name field contain the word University or College or Medical College or School then X return the expecting value.
2. Is it possible to create new fields through VBScript? If its possible then the X will split into two from its middle (3-3) and put the value in the newly generated column/fields.

If this possible it will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you can use InStr() to find out whether a string exists within another string

```
dim X   
if InStr([Name], "University") then
   X=101101 
elseif  InStr([Name], "Medical College") then 
  X=101103 
elseif  InStr([Name], "College") then 
  X=101102 
elseif  InStr([Name], "School") then 
  X=101104 
else 
  X=""
end if
```

Note that you'd have to change your logic slightly, running the If statement on "Medical College" before "College". In your original logic, the Instr function would assign X=101102 to both "College" and "Medical College" since the word "College" is found in each string.

Comment: I am facing some problem. Can you help me a little. I want a case insensitivity. If I wrote "college" instead of college its not returning anything. What should I do?

Comment: Use the syntax if InStr( LCase( [Name] ),"college" ) then

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.  You can create fields from a standalone VBScript, but not within Field Calculator.  See link below for how to write VBScript:

[Creating the geoprocessor object](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating%20the%20geoprocessor%20object)

I would recommend learning and using python instead for the task that you are trying to do.  You could use a [SearchCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000) to search for the field values, then [add your fields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000) based on the SearchCursor result and then [calculate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000).